# How to write a part of powershell command as a variable in python?

Tags: python

I have a powershell command to run it with winrm.

```
result  = session.run_ps('get-wmiobject -namespace root\SecurityCenter2 -computername localhost -Query "Select * from AntiVirusProduct"')
```

I want to give this part of command as a variable :

```
"Select * from AntiVirusProduct"
```

like :

```
query = "Select * from AntiVirusProduct"
result  = session.run_ps('get-wmiobject -namespace root\SecurityCenter2 -computername localhost -Query query')
```

How can i do it in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple f-string should do the trick here:

```
query = "Select * from AntiVirusProduct"
result  = session.run_ps(f'get-wmiobject -namespace root\\SecurityCenter2 -computername localhost -Query "{query}"')
```

Let me know if that works for you as I don't have a windows machine handy to test it on.

Comment: You're right, missed that thanks

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt work. Query is run in powershell like that : $query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service"
Get-WMIObject -Query $query

Comment: Sorry, I forgot " ". It works. Thank you

Comment: Yes thanks again to the comment from earlier for pointing out the need for quotes

Comment: Note that I also added a ```\``` to your string as you need to escape it in a Python string i.e. if you want the ```\``` character, write ```\\```